# If $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed, but not necessary independent random variables, does it imply that $P(X<Y)=P(X>Y)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> If $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed, but not necessary
>   independent random variables, does it imply that $P(X<Y)=P(X>Y)$?

I think they are equal, here is my proof of the discrete case:
$$
P(X<Y)=\sum_{t_i} P(X<Y|Y=t_i)P(Y=t_i)=\sum_{t_i}P(X<t_i)P(Y=t_i)
$$
and
$$
P(Y<X)=\sum_{t_i} P(Y<X|X=t_i)P(X=t_i)=\sum_{t_i}P(Y<t_i)P(X=t_i)=\sum_{t_i}P(X<t_i)P(Y=t_i)
$$

The correct answer is that they are not necessarily equal, why?

Comment: Well, you say they aren't necessarily independent.  So, say that $X$ is the throw of a fair die and $Y=X-1$ (with the convention that $X=1\implies Y=6$).  Just as an example.

Comment: How do your proofs show the equality?

Comment: Note:  your computation in the discrete case is not correct.  $P(Y<X\,|\,X=t_i)\neq P(Y<t_i)$ (as my earlier example shows).

Comment: @MichaelBurr I have shown it in the main body.

Comment: @lulu your example is great, but why that formula is not true, shouldn't it explain as *if $X=t_i$, what is the probability of P(Y<X)*, therefore it is should equal to $P(Y<t_i)$.

Comment: As I say, my example shows that the formula is false (in general).  If the variables are dependent then knowing the value of $X$ gives you information about the value of $Y$...your formula suggests that we can discard that information.

Comment: Just to stress, in my example take $t_i=3$.  Then knowing $X=3$ tells us that $Y=2$ so $P(Y<X\,|\,X=3)=1$.  Knowing the value of $X$ specifies the value of $Y$ exactly!  Of course $P(Y<3)=\frac 13$.

Comment: @lulu your explain is clear, but I am still struggling with the applying the bayes rule and the law of total probability, what's wrong with bayes rule?

Comment: @lulu I understand, when writing the law of total probability, I should add the dependence information at both sides of the equation. Like this:$P(X<Y|dependence information)=\sum_{t_i}P(X<Y|info, Y=t_i)P(Y=t_i|info)$

Comment: Noting wrong with the bayes rule. As shown by @lulu, the conditional probability doesn't equal to $P(Y<t_i)$; when $X$ is given, $Y$ is also known. The equation is true if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Granted, in general you need to incorporate the dependence into your computation, is that what you meant?  Here, of course, we don't know anything about the nature of the dependence...so there really isn't much to compute.

Comment: @lulu I just mean that when blindly writing the law of total probability as I did in the main body, it is dangerous when they are somehow dependent. One should write that part in the condition also.

Comment: @fizis I was writing and accidentally pressed 'Enter'.

Comment: @LeiHao Thanks for the comment, I think I understand where my derivation goes wrong.

Comment: Not sure what your point is.  The Law of Total Probability is just $P(A)=\sum P(A\,|\,B_i)P(B_i)$.  This is true regardless of dependence.

Comment: @lulu However when $X$ and $Y$ are dependent, what $P(X<Y)$ means is actually $P(X<Y|\text{dependence info known})$, isn't it?

Comment: No.  $P(X<Y)$ means "the probability that $X$ is less than $Y$".  Of course, the value will depend on the nature of $X,Y$ and their dependence.

Comment: Phrased differently:  $P(X<Y)$ is a question about the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$.  Of course, you need to know something about that joint distribution in order to compute $P(X<Y)$.  All the dependence information is contained in that joint distribution.

Comment: @lulu I think it is just a different point of view. Assume we have written the formula as in my main body. When we calculate it, we are really **conditioning on** the dependence of $X$ and $Y$. Therefore, write this condition out explicitly has nothing wrong.

Comment: Ok.  That seems like a matter of personal preference....I agree that spelling out information doesn't hurt.  I should add:  given how easy it is to get confused in questions about probability, perhaps it's not a bad idea to write more things out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your calculation is that
$$
\operatorname{Pr}(X<t_i|Y=t_i)
$$
is not the same as
$$
\operatorname{Pr}(X<t_i)
$$
when $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.  In the first case, we know what the value of $Y$ is so there is some influence on $X$'s distribution.  In the second case, $Y$ is not restricted.